# Is it possible to have an index page for taxonomy term for each custom post type it is assigned to?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-post-type-archives, template-hierarchy

I currently have a setup where I have a custom taxonomy that is link to the Wordpress post post type and another custom post type.

Since the custom taxonomy is assigned to the two post types mentioned, the taxonomy term index page displays all the post assigned that that term regardless of the custom post type it was added to.

So right now, I have the `location` taxonomy assigned to the `post` and `events` post types.

The posts and events archive pages have different template views. What I am trying to figure out if it is possible to have an index page for the location taxonomy where it will be able to display the posts assigned to a location and separate it according to the custom post type.

So if I have the taxonomy location terms Asia and Europe, I would like to find a way to have an archive page for the **Asia** and **Europe** posts for the `post` and `events` types separately.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Do they need to be the same taxonomy? Simplest solution would be to have two different taxonomies: `post_taxonomy` and `location_taxonomy`, for example.

Comment: @JacobPeattie yes I have thought of separating them but what I am trying to do (though I know it wont be simple on my part) is to keep is simple for the user because the post and events post types share common locations and it would be better if when a location is added, it will automatically be available for both posts and events.

Answer (score 1):

A simple method would be to create a archive template file for the `location` taxonomy, and then include the proper inner-template for each post type.

First, create a PHP file in your theme's root folder, named `taxonomy-location.php`. Then, you can use `get_post_type()` insider this template the include the proper template:

```
get_template_part( 'templates', get_post_type() . '-content' );
```

Now, you can create 2 different PHP files named `template-content.php` and `template-location-content.php`. Feel free to edit the to suit your styles.

Comment: I think she was asking about having separate indexes for each post type, not different templates for individual posts on the one index.

Comment: That wouldn't be possible. What if a term is assigned to both post types?

Comment: Thanks Jack, @JacobPeattie is right. I am aiming to have a separate archive pages for the terms for each post type.

Comment: You should create a new taxonomy. A term can be assigned to multiple post types in your case, which can break the code. @Jeda